# Why is Python concatenating strings in a list rather than iterating over them?

Tags: python, list

In a Python CGI script, I have lists of strings which are keys to a hash:

```
APPENDIX_WEBSITES = ['CJSHayward']
MAIN_WEBSITES = ['Alfresco',
  'Bible',
  'Fathers',
  'MyCollab',
  'Koha',
  'MediaWiki',
  'Moodle',
  'RequestTracker',
  'SuiteCRM',
  'TikiWiki',
  'Wordpress']
# The variable "data" is populated with a hash containing all above entries as keys.
sys.stderr.write(repr(MAIN_WEBSITES) + '\n')
sys.stderr.write(repr(APPENDIX_WEBSITES) + '\n')
sys.stderr.write(repr(MAIN_WEBSITES + APPENDIX_WEBSITES) + '\n')
for website in MAIN_WEBSITES + APPENDIX_WEBSITES:
    sys.stderr.write(website)
```

The Apache log faithfully records:

```
[Tue Aug 08 16:25:34.266769 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 16429] [client 127.0.0.1:40600] AH01215: ['Alfresco', 'Bible', 'Fathers', 'MyCollab', 'Koha', 'MediaWiki', 'Moodle', 'RequestTracker', 'SuiteCRM', 'TikiWiki', 'Wordpress']: /usr/local/websites/home/www/configure/index.cgi, referer: http://localhost/
[Tue Aug 08 16:25:34.267050 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 16429] [client 127.0.0.1:40600] AH01215: ['CJSHayward']: /usr/local/websites/home/www/configure/index.cgi, referer: http://localhost/
[Tue Aug 08 16:25:34.267268 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 16429] [client 127.0.0.1:40600] AH01215: ['Alfresco', 'Bible', 'Fathers', 'MyCollab', 'Koha', 'MediaWiki', 'Moodle', 'RequestTracker', 'SuiteCRM', 'TikiWiki', 'Wordpress', 'CJSHayward']: /usr/local/websites/home/www/configure/index.cgi, referer: http://localhost/
[Tue Aug 08 16:25:34.267490 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 16429] [client 127.0.0.1:40600] AH01215: AlfrescoAlfrescoBibleBibleFathersFathersMyCollabMyCollabKohaKohaMediaWikiMediaWikiMoodleMoodleRequestTrackerRequestTrackerSuiteCRMSuiteCRMTikiWikiTikiWiki: /usr/local/websites/home/www/configure/index.cgi, referer: http://localhost/
```

I am surprised that it seems to be iterating once over a single string (a redundant concatenation of the list), instead of iterating over what `repr` seems to recognize as a list of strings, which is what I intended.

How can I get the loop to iterate over 'Alfresco', 'Bible', etc. up through 'CJSHayward'?

Comment: It DID iterate over the individual website names.  However, you wrote them out without any newlines, so they all got run together on output.  If you want them as separate lines in the log, add a newline to them, just as you did for the first three lines.

Comment: `sys.stderr.write(repr(MAIN_WEBSITES) + '\n')` is just writing the list as a string with a newline appended.

Comment: `for website in MAIN_WEBSITES + APPENDIX_WEBSITES:
    sys.stderr.write(website)` iterates the concatenated lists, but `sys.stderr.write` does not append a newline by default. So, it *appears* that you are getting concatenation of strings, but you're not. If you want a newline after each call to `write`, you must be explicit: `sys.stderr.write('{}\n'.format(website))`

Comment: You forgot the `+ '\n'` inside your loop. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Use `print(<whatever>, file=sys.stderr)` for greater ease

Answer (score 1):

As commenters have indicated, you must append a newline character (`\n`) to `website` in order for each website to appear on it's own line in the Apache log.

```
for website in MAIN_WEBSITES + APPENDIX_WEBSITES:
    sys.stderr.write(website + '\n')
```

That is will resolve your issue.  However, **it may interest you to know *why* this resolves the issue**.

It's not crazy to expect that each call to `sys.stderr.write` would result its own line in the log.  The reason this is *not* the case is because `sys.stderr` is a stream.  A stream is an abstraction for data being sent somewhere.  In this case, `sys.stderr.write` *writes* to the standard error stream, and your Apache log *reads* from the standard error stream.  The Apache log does not know how many times you have called `sys.stderr.write`.  It only knows what it can see in the stream.  For example, it is impossible for the Apache log to know the difference between

```
sys.stderr('HelloWorld')
```

and

```
sys.stderr('Hello')
sys.stderr('World')
```

In both cases, Apache log (and other applications that read from standard error) just see the stream of characters `'HelloWorld'`. **For this reason, Apache log *must* use the newline character (`\n`) to divide the standard error stream into separate lines.**